# Apply map topography to my NurbsCurve?

Tags: snapping

I'm a newbie and I'm working on a race track based on my neighbourhood. So I used GIS addon to download my area as an object with topography. Then I made NurbsCurve following the track I'd like to make.
Now thing is my Curve is not actually alligned to my terrain and I don't really know how to do it. If it's possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out I can move every (point?) of my curve and snap it by Z axis to the closest face of terrain. Seems like it works.

Comment: *Shrink Wrap* modifier does that automatically